# Mysql: how to get Inverse result for given condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a query to get exactly opposite of result, what my query produces.

**query 1:**

```
select count(*) from DB.titlecard tt 
    join _date d on d.td_id = tt.td_id
    join sometask s on s.s_id = tt.s_id and d.em_id = s.em_id
    where d.`date` > "2019-01-01";
```

it gives me count of **21354** result.

**query 2:** (Similar query without sometask join)

```
select count(*) from DB.titlecard tt 
    join _date d on d.td_id = tt.td_id
    where d.`date` > "2019-01-01";
```

which produces **28984**

i need records which is difference of query 2 - query 1

something like this,
but it gives 1000 000 records.

```
select count(*) from DB.titlecard tt 
        join _date d on d.td_id = tt.td_id
        join sometask s on s.s_id <> tt.s_id and d.em_id = s.em_id
        where d.`date` > "2019-01-01";
```

i know to get difference by comparing both query.

but i am looking for better way within single query (because i have added only one more table in query 1)

this alone was the difference,
query 1:

```
join sometask s on s.s_id = tt.s_id
```

condition i want to apply,

```
join sometask s on s.s_id <> tt.s_id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your `JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` and then select only the rows where `s.id` is `NULL` you will get the count you want:

```
select count(*) from DB.titlecard tt 
    join _date d on d.td_id = tt.td_id
    left join sometask s on s.s_id = tt.s_id and d.em_id = s.em_id
    where d.`date` > "2019-01-01" and s.s_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: how do i missed it.. thanks @Nick. i got my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be quite complicated -- particularly if there are `NULL` values or duplicate rows.  I am guessing, though, that this does what you want:

```
select count(*) - count(s.s_id)
from DB.titlecard tt join
     d
     on d.td_id = tt.td_id left join
     sometask s
     on s.s_id = tt.s_id and d.em_id = s.em_id
where d.`date` > '2019-01-01';
```